# Tree chart migration from d3.v3 to d3.v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created organization chart using d3.js v3 version

pen - https://s.codepen.io/bumbeishvili/debug/yayErR

I want to add several features, and I also want to migrate it to d3.v4 
So, I have started migration process
in this pen - https://codepen.io/bumbeishvili/pen/RodMYG?editors=0010

Changes, that affects that migration process is following
1. d3.layout.tree => d3.tree
2. d3 zoom behavior changed, so it has also broke code
3. most important change (that affected almost every chart) was   different rules of enter exit selection between versions

What problems I have?

- I have difficulties with smoothly changing of these lines

  ```
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
    links = tree.links(nodes);
  ```

  **question 1 - How can I change above, so rest of the code functions normally?**
- For drawing links, I am using diagonal function, which looks like this:

  ```
  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()  
   .projection(function(d) {  
    return [d.x + Width / 2, d.y + Height / 2];  
  });
  ```

  **question 2 - what wiil be alternative of above so that other lines of code will not change?**
- **question 3 - Is there any universal ways to change v3 code to v4 so that it's enter & exit behavior stays the same?**

this  is jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/augburto/YMa2y/ which draws simpler chart (mine is based on that),

**question4 - Can anyone tell what changes must be applied to these jsfiddle chart for displaying correctly on d3.v4 ?**